# I have a problem with the favicon on the IE browser in an Angular 5 project

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, favicon

When I start to load the page I see my favicon, but when the page has finished loading everything, my favicon disappears and the browser shows the default favicon.

Do you have any advice to fix this problem?

I have not encountered any problems with other browsers, even with Edge.

I used https://realfavicongenerator.net/ to generate the favicons.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./assets/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="194x194" href="./assets/favicons/favicon-194x194.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="./assets/favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./assets/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="./assets/favicons/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="./assets/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#000000">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./assets/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="***MY PROJECT***">
<meta name="application-name" content="***MY PROJECT***">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="./assets/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

I added the classic favicon [favicon.ico] in root folder.

This is the manifest file.

```
{
"name": "***MY PROJECT***",
"short_name": "***MY PROJECT***",
"icons": [
    {
        "src": "/android-chrome-36x36.png",
        "sizes": "36x36",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/android-chrome-48x48.png",
        "sizes": "48x48",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/android-chrome-72x72.png",
        "sizes": "72x72",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/android-chrome-96x96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/android-chrome-144x144.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/android-chrome-192x192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/android-chrome-256x256.png",
        "sizes": "256x256",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/android-chrome-384x384.png",
        "sizes": "384x384",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/android-chrome-512x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
    }
],
"theme_color": "#ffffff",
"background_color": "#ffffff"
```

}

This is browserconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<browserconfig>
    <msapplication>
        <tile>
            <square70x70logo src="/mstile-70x70.png"/>
            <square150x150logo src="/mstile-150x150.png"/>
            <square310x310logo src="/mstile-310x310.png"/>
            <TileColor>#ffffff</TileColor>
        </tile>
    </msapplication>
</browserconfig>
```

Maybe I made some settings wrong during the generation.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Have you tried to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error?

Comment: Besides, I suggest you check the IE browser version, and refer to this article to make a [Compatibility test](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility_test#.XA-FJWgzaUk). If your are using IE 11, please check [this article](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility#.XA-FomgzaUl).

Answer (score 1):

in your index.html change to:

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="16x16" href="./assets/favicons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the change of the type tag doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

Image name should be favicon.ico and format should be ico
Place the ico in "wwwroot" folder
ico reference in index.html should be

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Edge doesn't show favicon while running from local. Deploy in webserver and try

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my scenario the issue was happening because I was deploying the app in a folder under the webserver root, something like this www.server.com/app1 . The only solution I found to make the icon works was to have two entries for the favicon tag, the one that comes with angular and one more entry that includes the folder path to where the app was being deployed.

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/app1/favicon.ico">
```

Also remember to clear the IE cache after you deploy your code, If you had your app as a favorite, after you change your favicon remove it from favorites and add it again...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was caused by an Apache rewrite rule.
Our application is served on `/domain/app` (`--base-href /domain/app`), so we need Apache to redirect to `index.html` for page refreshes or navigation outside of the base URL such as `/domain/app/foo` otherwise we have got 404.

Original .htaccess

```sh
RewriteEngine On
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ index.html
```

IE 11 does not requests `favicon.ico` similarly to other browsers.

IE 11 does this request for favicon (base href `/domain/app`):
Browser URL:
`/domain/app/foo/123`
Favicon request:
`/domain/app/foo/favicon.ico`

Other browsers (Chrome...):
Favicon request:
`/domain/app/favicon.ico`

The rewrite rule returned `index.html` for requested favicon.ico.

So I have added following piece of configuration code:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/(.*)/favicon\.ico$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) favicon.ico [L]
```

Moreover IE cached the `index.html` for the favicon request and IE stopped asking for `favicon.ico`.

I had to clear the cache using `inetcpl.cpl`:

[image: IE11 clear cache]